# I have a 500MB Frontier and I tried connecting a GIGA router to Giga switch but the speed test only shows 100MB speed

Tags: internet-speed

I have a 500MB Frontier and I tried connecting a Gigabit router to Gigabit switch but the speed test only shows 100MB speed.

Comment: 100-125MB appears to be about right. 1Gb = 1000Mb. 8 bits = 1 Byte.

Comment: You need to clarify MB vs Mb [mega**byte** vs mega**bit**]. Do we assume 'Frontier' is an ISP?? No consumer ISP offers a 500MB connection, fastest is about 1MB, 1Gb, 1000Mb.